When using Google Colab, Python package 'datasets' just disappeared from virtualenv directory 'site-packages'
I'm using Google Colab and trying make a virtual environment to work.
My code is:
  from google.colab import drive
  drive.mount('/content/drive')

  !pip install virtualenv
  myenv_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/virtual_env/' 
  !virtualenv {myenv_dir}
  !chmod +x {myenv_dir}bin/pip;
  !chmod +x {myenv_dir}bin/activate;
  !source {myenv_dir}bin/activate; pip install accelerate==0.29.3 -U
  !source {myenv_dir}bin/activate; pip install datasets==2.19.1

  import sys
  packages_dir = myenv_dir + "lib/python3.10/site-packages/"
  sys.path.append(packages_dir)

  import accelerate
  import datasets

This code runs ok and at this moment I can import both accelerate and datasets packages. I look at the Google Drive file explorer and the subdirectories are there,both for accelerate and datasets.
Now I disconnect the notebook, reconnect it and run just the code below (enough to connect to the virtual environment and start using the packages without reinstalling them on Collab):
  drive.mount('/content/drive')
  myenv_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/virtual_env/' 
  !chmod +x {myenv_dir}bin/activate;
  !source {myenv_dir}bin/activate;
  import sys
  packages_dir = myenv_dir + "lib/python3.10/site-packages/"
  sys.path.append(packages_dir)
  import accelerate
  import datasets 

And here comes the weird part: import accelerate works fine. import datasets returns a

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datasets'.

If look in the directory tree either in Colab's file explorer or in Google Drive the accelerate subdirectory is there but the datasets directory in gone. Just vanished.
I'm at a loss on what's happening here!

Try this:
!export PYTHONPATH='/content/drive/MyDrive/virtual_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/'
print(sys.path) 
import datasets

Seems to be the order of sys.path is causing failure to find the library.
check: https://www.devdungeon.com/content/python-import-syspath-and-pythonpath-tutorial


I replicate your steps.

Follow steps you defined.
Delete session
Verify folder in Google Drive, both accelerate and datasets are there.
Import both successfully.

Can you clarify how you:
Now I disconnect the notebook, reconnect it and run just the code below

In my repo I delete active session.


In the Colab notebook interface I clicked first in: Runtime and then in Disconnect and delete runtime. I then checked in Active Sessions and there was no other session running.

this will cause to allocate a new VM hence what you are seeing is expected. IIRC accelerate is part of Colab already.

But the contents of both packages (datasets and accelerate) were saved in Google Drive, not in VM's /contents. Besides, why datasets remain visible in Google Drive after VM's reloading  while accelerate's disappeared? If this is expected, then what is the rule that makes datasets's contents remain there and accelerate's to vanish?

About IIRC accelerate being part of Colab already, yes it is, but the latest version of it is incompatible with the lastest version of datasets. After some tweaking I found that accelerate=0.29.3 and datasets=2.19.1 were the ones that worked together. Since I have to reinstall them each time I restart the VM, I tought about saving the contents in a venv in Google Drive and load the packages from there next time. But this weird behavior of Colab and Drive prevents me from doing this, so far.

Have you looked into Colab Enterprise that will allow you to preserve the environment and libraries?

I'm using Colab Pro. I will take a look in Enterprise. But in any case, this seems to me like a bug in the interface between Colab and Drive. About the error, in your case, are you using Pro or Enterprise?

I agree, Python sys should be preserved, will take a look again. I was using basic version
